# WebRTC: A send Offer to B, if B does not return Answer to A. Is there a timeout?

Tags: webrtc

In WebRTC, A send Offer to B, if B does not return Answer to A. Is there a timeout? I had a try when B return Answer one hour later, Answer also works.

Comment: sendOfferToRemote(); // put offer creation here
waitForAnswerInBackgroundThread(); //wait for answer here, timeout after x time

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no timeout. You can take as long as you want to create an answer and send it back (I just verified using our own apps). You can set a timeout in your app though, which when fired can cancel the call and signal the remote peer that an answer is no longer necessary.

Having said that, I would advise against this. Your users are your free timeout functionality, they will hang up when it takes too long. ICE negotiation can take very long, depending on your route. So a timeout might cancel a call that was otherwise going to be perfectly fine, just a little slow to get started.

Comment: This assumes the user's network topology hasn't changed in the meantime, e.g. user moves from one WiFi network to another.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "very long". If by "ICE negotiation" you mean sending the ice candidates over signaling as they are discovered, then the longest I've seen that take to exhaustively *finish* is 20 seconds, but that is just it being thorough, and a peer connection often seems established way before that process ends (and the null candidate is returned).

Comment: @jib I've worked on apps that use webrtc for 2 years now. I have seen ICE negotiation (the process of gathering ICE candidates and setting them on both sides) take over two minutes occasionally. It's usually the generation of ICE candidates that bottlenecks this process. If you move from one network to the other you are going to have to do the whole process from scratch anyway, because you will lose your connection to your signaling server.

Comment: The OP was talking about using an answer an hour later. A lot can happen in an hour.

Comment: @jib OP asked if the mechanism came with a callback, which is not the case. I simply explained how one could implement a timeout himself. Network changes are beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I see no mention of callbacks in the OP's question. Instead, he seems to be asking whether there's a time after which an answer will no longer work (that exceeds one hour). I think your answer would be better if it included the prerequisites for an answer working this long after the offer.

Comment: @jib I'm sorry, I meant timeout, not callback. There is no timeout, I verified by waiting a long time (15+ minutes) before sending the answer back. I don't see how the question is not answered, unless you want to actually wait for an hour, which I think is silly, but go ahead and post your results in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. This depends on your signaling mechanism. The signaling mechanism is responsible for offer/answer exchange and is implemented outside of WebRTC. It can be done with or without timeout.